# Django REST: Show details and list on 1 url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

There is a Django project that uses a REST API.

Most of the url-patterns follow the same paradigm:

```
/foo_config/1
```

Basically `/list-view/details-view`

But there is another type of config - which can only have 1 object, so showing it like `/bar_config/1` is confusing, because user might expect #2 and #3, etc.

I would like to 'map' `bar_config` details and list together using simple `/bar_config`.

Tried using `@detail_route`, but it doesn't work:

```
@detail_route(methods=['put'])
def put_config(self, request):
  ...
```

How to achieve my goal?

**UPDATE:** after trying to play with `detail_route` and Ivan Semochkin answer - still no luck. I will provide more details on what I have:

`/accounts/foo_account/bar_config/` <-- list view
`/accounts/foo_account/bar_config/1` <-- details view

Accounts defined as:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('accounts', AccountViewSet)
```

The goal is to:

1. Show `bar_config/1` on `bar_config` (PUT on LIST page);
2. Prohibit/hide `bar_config/1`;
3. Allow to view and update info, prohibit to create/delete;

I will summarize: I need to change the way a sub-link works in the existing project, that already uses `DefaultRouter` for all its patterns. This sub-link maps singleton-model. I would like to show update (PUT) data on the list (GET) page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you just override `list` method?

```
class ConfigViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = Config.objects.all()  
    serializer_class = ConfigSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
   
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_queryset().first()
        # using 'first' will retrieve first instance
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

It will work fine it you don't only show that model. If you want to provide some CRUD, then inherit from `ModelViewSet` and override `delete` and `update` methods.
**Update for comment**
Another way to do it - create a custom router, with this router you don't need to use `list`, use retrieve instead

```
from rest_framework.routers import Route, SimpleRouter

class CustomRouter(SimpleRouter):
"""
A router for update and retrieve without lookup field.
"""
    routes = [
       Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/$',
            mapping={'put': 'update'},
            name='{basename}-update',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Update'}
        ),
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/$',
            mapping={'get': 'retrieve'},
            name='{basename}-detail',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Detail'}
        ),
    ]
```

ViewSet:

```
class ConfigViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Config.objects.all()  
    serializer_class = ConfigSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_queryset().first()
        # using 'first' will retrieve first instance
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_queryset().first()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data)
        # you could also provide `partial=True` in serializer for partial update
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save() 
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

urls:

```
router = CustomRouter()
router.register('config', ConfigViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: I need a read-only model (no create, no delete). Also want to be able to PUT directly on the list view.

Comment: @h3d0 so you could use `ModelViewSet` instead and do the same thing which I did with `retrieve` method. But one problem with `put`, you'll need override default url, because by default it w8 lookup field, like pk in retrieve.

Comment: That is point of question: how to override the default url in `put`.

Comment: @h3d0 did I help you?

Comment: I have updated the question. Looks like provided details were not enough. Not sure if it is possible to add `CustomRouter` to the existing `DefaultRouter` (since this is what project already use all over the place).

Comment: Anyway, looks good, but it doesn't fully work - it shows correct editable fields, but they are empty and page returns 405.

Comment: @h3d0 in that case I recommend you use a plain `APIView` or `GenericApiView` instead of viewset. Just create 2 separate view